# python program suddenly started throwing KeyError

Tags: python

I am making an API request to a server and then parsing the json response and saving it to a csv file. Everything was working but now suddenly, the program is throwing errors.

Weird part is that when I run the same code on my laptop it works but on the vps, it's throwing exception (it was working on vps as well just moments ago, and nothing has changed on the vps that could cause the exception).

**my python code:**

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger
import requests
import json
import csv
from datetime import datetime


print("Started...")
def fn():
    print("        Writing Data...")
    session_id = "auZsJ4F2RsQNJxSPTMDt2238324"
    Outlook='http://www.myfxbook.com/api/get-community-outlook.json?session=' + session_id
    Outlook_response = requests.get(Outlook)
    Outlook_data = Outlook_response.json()['symbols']
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")


    EURUSD=Outlook_data[0]
    SHORTPERC0=EURUSD['shortPercentage']
    LONGPERC0 =EURUSD['longPercentage']
    SHORTvolume0=EURUSD['shortVolume']
    longVolume0=EURUSD['longVolume']
    longPositions0=EURUSD['longPositions']
    shortPositions0=EURUSD['shortPositions']

    with open('myfile.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow([current_time, SHORTvolume0, longVolume0, longPositions0, shortPositions0])

        print("        done...")

sched = BlockingScheduler()

# Execute fn() at the start of each minute.
sched.add_job(fn, trigger=CronTrigger(second=1))
sched.start()
```

**these are the errors:**

[image]

Is the error related to APScheduler? Or is it a key error?

**json response looks like this:**

```
{
"error": false,
"message": "",
"symbols": [{
    "name": "EURUSD",
    "shortPercentage": 45,
    "longPercentage": 55,
    "shortVolume": 23273.25,
    "longVolume": 28123.5,
    "longPositions": 74045,
    "shortPositions": 60996,
    "totalPositions": 135041,
    "avgShortPrice": 1.1709,
    "avgLongPrice": 1.1975
}
```

Comment: the dict ` Outlook_response.json()` does not have the key  symbols

Comment: hi thanks for the response @balderman but i can clearly see from the response that there is a key "symbols" in the response

Comment: print the dict before you look for the key. are you sure its there?

Comment: It is absolutely the case that the dictionary doesn't have the 'symbols' key. I can't tell you how many times I wasted time debugging on a presumption I know what the data is, by relying on what I _think_ the data is. As @balderman says, `Outlook_response_parsed = Outlook_response.json(); print(Outlook_response_parsed); Outlook_data = Outlook_response_parsed['symbols']` to be absolutely sure which data triggers the error.

Comment: is it possible that the received response on one computer is different from the response received on the other computer ?

Comment: @Sanders: yes, it is possible. It is even possible to get varying responses when repeating the same action several times. When scraping data, you can never be sure you get what you want to get. There may be a problem with internet connection, timeouts, website detecting bots and blocking you out... and you have to deal with it.

Comment: well then there is nothing i can do , because the website itself provide the api key so that user can make api  calls build their own apps around it , but it seems like they are blocking the access so there is not point in even trying

Answer (score 1):

That has something to do with the server, and it can't even get the JSON response itself, not the `symbols` key missing. That error may occur most of the time, you can just ignore it, or handle it as follows.

```
try:
    Outlook_data = Outlook_response.json()['symbols']
except:
    print("An error has occurred while getting the data. Please try again later.")
```

Comment: I don't know why somebody has voted this answer down because what it says is right. While scraping, getting no response is very common and it can have various reasons (e.g., timeouts, website detecting bots and blocking you out...). It's the responsibility of the developer to recognize this and to deal with these situations.

Comment: totally agree with this answer and other answers as well ,

Comment: If the response was not received, you would be getting a `TimeoutError`, or some kind of `ConnectionError`. If the server returned an empty response or something that is not valid JSON, you would get something like `JSONDecodeError`. If The response was the string `null`, you'd get a `TypeError`. A `KeyError` from OP's error message can only be raised in that line if the connection was successful, response was received and is a valid JSON of a dictionary (and this dictionary lacks the `symbols` key), which means the first sentence of this answer is demonstrably wrong.

Comment: Furthermore: ignoring an error from an operation that seems to be necessary for the further calculation is hardly a solution to a problem, unless OP explicitly notes that it is an incidental operation where an error is ignorable; and a bare `except`, catching any and all errors, is an [antipattern](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E722.html), and should almost never be used.

Comment: @Amadan, I agree with your comments. I haven't formulated _my_ comment properly, the answer does have some faults - but I didn't like that somebody has put down the answer that at least showed a possible direction (i.e., use try/except) _without commenting why_ and _without offering a better solution_. Thank you for giving valuable details.

Comment: @lenka_cizkova: There _is_ no better solution because the diagnostics (per multiple comments) has not been performed. The cause is the missing key in the dictionary; how to "solve" it requires knowing what actually came back from the server, and input from OP as to how they want to handle it. Imagine a patient who gets blisters when baking. Good: Ask whether they touch hot metal, then maybe see if gloves are viable. "It has to do with a knife. In kitchen, pain may occur most of the time, you can just ignore it, or acknowledge that there was pain and try baking again later"? Not so much.

Answer (score 1):

this may work for you :

```
    Request = 'https://www.myfxbook.com/api/login.json?email=username&password=password'
    response = requests.get(Request, verify = False)
    data = response.json()
    Session = data['session']
    path = ('https://www.myfxbook.com/api/get-community-outlook.json?session=' + Session)
    Outlook_response = requests.get(path, verify = False)
    Outlook_data = Outlook_response.json()['symbols']
```

to not get blocked for making many request use defferent **user-agent** header

for example :

```
headers = {
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36'
}
Outlook_response = requests.get(Outlook, headers=headers)
Outlook_data = Outlook_response.json()['symbols']
```

Comment: the website itself provided the api access to the paid users to make the api calls twice per   minute so that user can make his/her own solutions using the data

Comment: will try the updated answer and update here how it goes